# r test for a criteria in a column and if not met, move to next number and test again

Tags: r, loops

This is quite complicated for me and I would be really grateful if someone could tell me how to go about this problem. My dataframe has two columns:

```
dat <- structure(list(day = 172:208,
                      x = c(0.14, 0.02, 0.09, 3.06, 3.21, 
                            4.15, 6.24, 6.27, 3.31, 6.28, 
                            16.9, 20.1, 20.29, 20.45, 17.52, 
                            6.22, 1.14, 0.84, 0.68, 0.49, 
                            0.22, 0.01, 0.01, 0.6, 0.64, 0.64, 
                            0.66, 0.69, 0.15, 0.15, 3.16, 
                            3.44, 3.42, 3.37, 3.51, 2.77, 3.51
                      )),
                 .Names = c("day", "x"),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-37L))

dat
  day      x 
 172    0.14
 173    0.02
 174    0.09
 175    3.06
 176    3.21
 177    4.15
 178    6.24
 179    6.27
 180    3.31
 181    6.28
 182    16.90
 183    20.10
 184    20.29
 185    20.45
 186    17.52
 187    6.22
 188    1.14
 189    0.84
 190    0.68
 191    0.49
 192    0.22
 193    0.01
 194    0.01
 195    0.60
 196    0.64
 197    0.64
 198    0.66
 199    0.69
 200    0.15
 201    0.15
 202    3.16
 203    3.44
 204    3.42
 205    3.37
 206    3.51
 207    2.77
 208    3.51
```

What I want to do is this:

1) In column x, look for values greater than 2.3

```
which(x>2.3)
```

2) For the day where x is greater than 2.3, calculate the percentage change in x for next 3 days. For example, for 175 day, x is 3.06 (>2.3), therefore for next 3 consecutive values of x (3.21 - day 176, 4.15 - day 177, 6.24 - day 178), do this:

```
(3.21 - 3.06)*100/3.06 = 4.9
(4.15 - 3.21)*100/3.21 = 0.29
(6.24 - 4.15)*100/4.15 = 50.36
```

and if the all the above three values are greater than -30, then store the middle day from 176, 177 and 178 in a separate vector (in this case, store 177).

3) If the three values are less than -30, then start again from 179 (>2.3 mm) and repeat step 2 for day 180, 181 and 182.

```
   (3.31 - 6.27)*100/6.27 = -47.2
   (6. 28 - 3.31)*100/3.31 = 89.72
   (16.9 - 6.28) * 100/6.28 = 169.1
```

If all the values are greater than -30, then store the middle day (181). In this case, one of the values is less than -30, therefore do not store anything and start again fromfrom 183 (>2.3 mm) and repeat again for 184, 185 and 186. If a value out of 3 values above is again less than -30, start from day 187 (x > 2.3) and repeat step 2 for day 188,189 and 190. If again a single value out of three is less than -30, then start from 202 (since for 202, x > 2.3)

I am really sorry I do not have much programming experience here in r therefore posting this question which has bogged me down for quite a time.

Thanks a lot

Comment: OK, so would you repeat this for *every* day which has x > 2.3? Even if they are consecutive?

Comment: no i wont repeat it for each day. say, if a day is >2.3, then the next three days, do the percentage thing. and then move to the fourth day. I dont need to get back to the three days to test again for x>2.3.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with my question.  In your example, days 176, 177 and 178 all have x > 2.3.  So you begin the 3-day-interval-percentage thing starting on day 176 and so on.  Once that is done, do you then want to being another 3-day-interval algorithm, starting with day 177?  Or is it excluded because it was contained in the intervals which started on 176?

Comment: Hi thanks. 177 will be excluded since it was contained in the intervals.

Comment: Oh.  I wish I had known that; it looks like I just solved a different problem than the one you have!  So, in your example, you *only* need to define groups of 3 starting with day 175!  So there are only 11 groups of 3.  Is that right?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you. But if your code were to work, it would do this: it will select 175 first (since > 2.3) and do the percentage thing on 176,177,178 then it will move to 179 (since > 2.3) and do percentage for 180,181 and 182...then move to 183(>2.3), do it for 184,185,186, them move to 187 (>2.3) and do for 188,189, and 190 after that it will move to 202(>2.3) and do percentage for 203,204 and 205. I am sorry if I am not explaining things properly but I really appreciate your time. thank you

Comment: Therefore, in your example, the desired output would contain only 11 numbers. Correct?

Comment: the desired output in this case will have 4 numbers: 177,181,185,204. 177 because i) 175 > 0.23 ii) percentage change from 176 to 177 >-30%and 177 to 178 is > -30% therefore the middle of the three is chosen which is 177. same goes for others. rest of the pairs do not meet the criteria

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this without any loops, by using the new(ish) `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Let's calculate percent change first, as a new column:

```
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(change = (x-lag(x))/lag(x)*100)
```

Next, make a vector of subscripts that indicates which groups of 3 should be included in your answer.  In this chunk of code, we fine the first (`min`) value that matches your condition, count from there in intervals of 4, and then make those the "starting points" for our subscripts.  The last line simply makes this into a dataframe:

```
grps <- which(dat$x > 2.3) %>% 
  min %>%
  seq(from = ., to = nrow(dat), by = 4) %>%
  lapply('+',1:3) %>%
  do.call(c,.) %>%
  function(l) data.frame(group = gl(length(l)/3,3), ss = l)
```

Then you use those group subscripts (`ss`) to pull out the necessary rows of `dat`. Let's look at the top of the new dataframe before proceeding:

```
grps %>%
  do(data.frame(.,dat[.$ss,])) %>%
  head

   group ss day     x     change
5      1  5 176  3.21   4.901961
6      1  6 177  4.15  29.283489
7      1  7 178  6.24  50.361446
9      2  9 180  3.31 -47.208931
10     2 10 181  6.28  89.728097
11     2 11 182 16.90 169.108280
```

As you can see, the values for days 176, 177 and 178 exactly match those in your example.  This is a group for which we will want the middle number, since all of `change` is greater than -30.   We *won't* use 181, however, because one value of `change` in that group ("`group 2`") is less than -30.  Again, this matches the original question.

Then group by `group` (which keeps data in sets of 3).  Finally you filter the data by change > -30 and select only the middle row:

```
grps %>%
  do(data.frame(.,dat[.$ss,])) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(all(change > -30)) %>%
  do(.[2,])

  group ss day     x     change
1     1  6 177  4.15 29.2834891
2     3 14 185 20.45  0.7885658
3     6 26 197  0.64  0.0000000
4     8 34 205  3.37 -1.4619883
```

Comment: thanks. I will just try this with my dataset and will let you know. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: this looks good. but it does not give the desired results. For example, it does not select 181 even though i) 179 > 2.3, and ii)  percentage change from 180 to 181 & 181 to 182 is > - 30 (therefore it should select the middle date i,e, 181). On the contrary,it selects 197 but 195 is not > 2.3 and the percentage change from 196 to 197 and 197 to 198 is greater than -30. But still thanks for your time and efforts. I will try to read around the package and see if I can tweak your solution to fit mine.

Comment: On the contrary, 181 should **not** be selected (because the change for 180 was  -47, which is in the same group of three). As you say in your question above "In this case, one of the values is less than -30, therefore do not store anything and start again fromfrom 183"